# Windows Hardware Lab Package tab not available when tests are completed and passed

Tags: testing, automated-tests

I am getting to know the HLK Studio and have run the recommended tests against one of our drivers ( a USBStorageFilter driver). When the driver was selected in the list of available components on the test machine the studio recommended the "HyperVisor Code Integrity Readiness Test" and the "TDI Filters and LSPS are not allowed" only. These ran without error and the studio is now showing test status of total 2 & passed 2.

However the PACKAGE tab is greyed out and will not allow me to proceed in creating the package for submission. There is no indication of any other steps and the documentation suggests that once the selected tests have completed you should be able to move on to the Package tab.

Anyone got any clues as to what is preventing this from happening?

Windows 10 Pro x64 16209 target machine, 2016 server (hperv) as the HLK server studio machine.

Thanks

Nick

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue and the only thing I did was exit HLK and start it again. It remembered the results and the `Package` tab wasn't greyed out anymore. I was able to continue with package creation.